# .htaccess não permite entrar em pastas

Tags: cakephp, htaccess

Estou com um site em CakePHP e com seus devidos `htaccess` corretamente. O Problema ocorre porque eu criei um domínio adicional na hospedagem e como de costume, ele cria uma pasta na `public_html` para colocar os arquivos desse novo domínio ficando por exemplo `public_html/dominio2`. Eu joguei todos os arquivos ali, do outro site, só que por causa do htaccess, quando entro em www.dominio2.com.br ele me retorna `erro 500`. Se eu renomeio o `.htaccess` da raiz do Cake, então ele entra no `dominio2.com.br` só que os arquivos do cake ficam tudo bagunçados. O htaccess que tenho hoje

**htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

O que eu posso colocar ai para caso o pedido for para uma pasta, então ele entra na pasta e não efetua a passagem para webroot ?

Comment: seu cake está na raiz do public_html?

Comment: Sim, está na public_html

Comment: Coloca ele em uma outra pasta e aponta seu domínio pra essa pasta.

Comment: É a única saida ?

Comment: Essa é a mais fácil, mas você pode colocar uma condição pra ele não ler as regras para um domínio específico, mas vai ter q ficar adicionando sempre novos domínios.

Comment: Tente entrar na configuração do seu domínio e faça-o apontar diretamente para a sua pasta public_html

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa adicionar uma condição ao .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dominio1.com.br$ [NC]
    RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Dessa forma, quando você entrar no **dominio2.com.br**, ele não vai ler o RewriteRule do .htaccess do **dominio1**.